# Why is my for loop of body.replaceText function in Google Document Script stopping?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to write a merg script using goolge documents and referencing a seperate spreadsheet.

I am currently stuck, it doesn't replace any of the content and the forloop stops at i=0.

Here is the code:

```
function myMerger(body, myArrayOfWords, myArrayOfData){//this function will replace the terms found in myArrayOfWords with 
  Logger.log(' just starter myMerger');
  Logger.log('myArrayOfWords.length is '+myArrayOfWords.length);
  Logger.log('myArrayOfData.length is ' +myArrayOfData.length);
  for(i=0;i<myArrayOfWords.length;++i){//for loop replaces will run the following code for each string within myArrayOfWords
    Logger.log('myMerger forloop instance number '+i);
    Logger.log('replacing '+myArrayOfWords[i]+' with '+myArrayOfData[i]);
    body.replaceText(myArrayOfWords[i], myArrayOfData[i]);
    //replaces the string in the document with a value from myArrayOfData
  }
}
```

The logger returns the following:

> [14-04-24 12:07:40:248 PDT]  just starter myMerger
>     [14-04-24 12:07:40:248 PDT] myAraryOfWords.length is 23
>     [14-04-24 12:07:40:248 PDT] myArrayOfData.length is 23
>     [14-04-24 12:07:40:248 PDT] myMerger forloop instance number 0
>     [14-04-24 12:07:40:248 PDT] replacing **!WeekOf!** with 12

Then it stops. 
I can't tell if I just built a bad for loop or if there is an error that I am not aware of. I am not sure how to check for what is breaking it.

Comment: It appears that the (*) is causing the problem, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText%28String,String%29) always understands the string to be replaced as a regular expression pattern and `*` have a special meaning in a regexes. You should use `#`  or any other char that does not have a special meaning as your "separator".

Anyway, it's a "good practice" to escape everything if you're not expecting a regexp. Like this:

```js
function escapeRegex(s) { return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'); }

function myMerger(body, myArrayOfWords, myArrayOfData){//this function will replace the terms found in myArrayOfWords with 
  Logger.log(' just starter myMerger');
  Logger.log('myArrayOfWords.length is '+myArrayOfWords.length);
  Logger.log('myArrayOfData.length is ' +myArrayOfData.length);
  for(i=0;i<myArrayOfWords.length;++i){//for loop replaces will run the following code for each string within myArrayOfWords
    Logger.log('myMerger forloop instance number '+i);
    Logger.log('replacing '+myArrayOfWords[i]+' with '+myArrayOfData[i]);
    body.replaceText(escapeRegex(myArrayOfWords[i]), myArrayOfData[i]);
    //replaces the string in the document with a value from myArrayOfData
  }
}
```

I got this neat code from [Bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript/3561711#3561711).

By the way, you should have pasted the error message you got when you ran this code. It would've helped me to answer you faster:
`Invalid regular expression pattern **!WeekOf!**`

Comment: I hadn't seen any errors while running this code, are you referring the red box that shows above the terminal?